# How Would I Go About Merging & Transforming JS Objects In An Array

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array of objects such as below:

```js
const array = [
  {
    saleRef: 10,
    itemName: "Rum",
    supplier: "Rum Co Ltd",
    itemValue: 3.99,
    totalSale: 5.99
  },
  {
    saleRef: 10,
    itemName: "Coke",
    supplier: "Coke Co Ltd",
    itemValue: 2.0,
    totalSale: 5.99
  },
  {
    saleRef: 8,
    itemName: "Beer",
    supplier: "Berr Co Ltd",
    itemValue:c 2.99,
    totalSale: 2.99
  }
];
```

How can I create a new array of objects, that would look like this:

```js
const wantedArray = [
  {
    saleRef: 10,
    items: {
      item1: {
        itemName: "Rum",
        supplier: "Rum Co Ltd",
        itemValue: 3.99,
      },
      item2: {
        itemName: "Coke",
        supplier: "Coke Co Ltd",
        itemValue: 2.0,
      }
    },
    totalSale: 5.99
  },
  {
    saleRef: 8,
    itemName: "Beer",
    supplier: "Berr Co Ltd",
    itemValue: 2.99,
    totalSale: 2.99
  }
]
```

Essentially I want to iterate over a large array of objects, where some of those objects have a matching 'saleRef'. When the 'saleRef is matching', I want to merge those objects keeping the matching keys and values whilst moving other (should be unique) keys and values into a new key.

Where I am struggling the most with this is identifying when the saleRef matches.

```js
const newArray = array.map(sale => {
  if (sale.saleRef === sale.saleRef) {
    console.log(sale.saleRef);
  }
});

console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce`

Comment: You will probably need to be more specific on what the desired output is.

Comment: @riscarrott Thanks, I'll look further into it.

Comment: @Ben I've added further details, hopefully it makes sense

Comment: loop over each item use `shopID` to match where to put the item into `saleItems`, you basically need 1 for loop.. what have you tried?

Comment: Hi @LawrenceCherone, yeah I know I need a for loop to iterate over it or a forEach I guess, it's the content of that loop I'm unsure of. I'm just looking for pointers to further reading that anybody can suggest that is appropriate to my problem?

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which fields will be common?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you only really need a single loop, use a key from the item to create an object, and on each loop just add the item where its supposed to go. Then at end use `Object.values(result)` to get the object from the array.

**For example**

```js
var data = [{
    shopID: "1",
    registerID: "1",
    employeeID: "1",
    completed: "true",
    referenceNumber: "10001000150",
    refernceNumberSource: "Epos1",
    completeTime: "6/4/2017",
    TransactionQtySold: "2",
    TransactionTax: "2.82",
    TransactionTotalSales: "19.76",
    ItemSku: "380010",
    ItemDescription: "CRAFTSMAN'S KNIFE HVK",
    Supplier: "Knife Co Limited",
    Department: "KNIVES",
    Category: "FIXED BLADE",
    Price: "8.95",
    Cost: "2.63",
    QtySold: "1",
    Tax: "1.49",
    TotalSales: "10.44",
    BinLocation: "Z5"
  },
  {
    shopID: "1",
    registerID: "1",
    employeeID: "1",
    completed: "true",
    referenceNumber: "10001000150",
    refernceNumberSource: "Epos1",
    completeTime: "6/4/2017",
    TransactionQtySold: "2",
    TransactionTax: "2.82",
    TransactionTotalSales: "19.76",
    ItemSku: "BIOSA",
    ItemDescription: "SILICONE OIL AEROSOL",
    Supplier: "Oil Co Ltd",
    Department: "CHEMICAL & CLEANING",
    Category: "OILS & GREASES",
    Price: "7.99",
    Cost: "3.67",
    QtySold: "1",
    Tax: "1.33",
    TotalSales: "9.32",
    BinLocation: "D"
  },
  {
    shopID: "1",
    registerID: "1",
    employeeID: "1",
    completed: "true",
    referenceNumber: "10001000151",
    refernceNumberSource: "Epos1",
    completeTime: "6/4/2017",
    TransactionQtySold: "1",
    TransactionTax: "0.5",
    TransactionTotalSales: "3.5",
    ItemSku: "DIVE",
    ItemDescription: "DIVER'S TANK 232 BAR FILL",
    Supplier: "Air Co",
    Department: "AIR GUN",
    Category: "CHARGING",
    Price: "3",
    Cost: "0.01",
    QtySold: "1",
    Tax: "0.5",
    TotalSales: "3.5",
    BinLocation: ""
  }
]

var result = {};
for (const i in data) {
  result[data[i].shopID] = {
    shopID: data[i].shopID,
    registerID: data[i].registerID,
    employeeID: data[i].employeeID,
    completed: data[i].completed,
    referenceNumber: data[i].referenceNumber,
    refernceNumberSource: data[i].refernceNumberSource,
    completeTime: data[i].completeTime,
    TransactionQtySold: result[data[i]] && result[data[i]].TransactionQtySold ? result[data[i]].TransactionQtySold + data[i].TransactionQtySold : data[i].TransactionQtySold,
    TransactionTax: data[i].TransactionTax,
    TransactionTotalSales: result[data[i]] && result[data[i]].TransactionTotalSales ? result[data[i]].TransactionTotalSales + data[i].TransactionTotalSales : data[i].TransactionTotalSales,
    saleItems: {
      ...(!result[data[i].shopID] || result[data[i].shopID].saleItems || {}),
      ['Item' + (parseInt(i, 10) + 1)]: {
        ItemSku: data[i].ItemSku,
        ItemDescription: data[i].ItemDescription,
        Supplier: data[i].Supplier,
        Department: data[i].Department,
        Category: data[i].Category,
        Price: data[i].Price,
        Cost: data[i].Cost,
        QtySold: data[i].QtySold,
        Tax: data[i].Tax,
        TotalSales: data[i].TotalSales,
        BinLocation: data[i].BinLocation
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(Object.values(result)[0])
```

Comment: maybe need to parse them ints/floats though, but you get the idea

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. Unfortunately this solution misses the problem that we only want to merge those objects with a matching 'referenceNumber'

Comment: trivial fix, just change `result[data[i].shopID] = {` to `result[data[i].referenceNumber] = {` and do the sorting by that, then pick from the array the one you want instead of `Object.values(result)[0]` use `result['10001000150']`